# VBA code not running on Outlook restart

Tags: vba, outlook

When I close and relaunch Outlook the macro doesn't work.

This code will validate before sending the mail in Outlook for subject and attachments.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim lngAns                  As Long
Dim varArray                As Variant
Dim strWordFound            As String

varArray = Array("PFA", "Attached", "Enclosed", "File", "Report")

For lngCount = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
    If InStr(1, Item.Body, varArray(lngCount), vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Item.Subject, varArray(lngCount), vbTextCompare) Then
        strWordFound = strWordFound & "," & varArray(lngCount)
    End If
Next
strWordFound = Mid(strWordFound, 2)
If Len(strWordFound) > 0 And Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
    If MsgBox("Found No Attachments but the Word(s): " & _
                    strWordFound & vbTab & vbCr & "Do you want to send the mail anyway?", _
                            vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Attachment Missing") = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End If
If Len(Trim(Item.Subject)) = 0 Then
    If MsgBox("Subject is Empty. Are you sure you want to send the Mail?", _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Subject Missing") = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code cannot run at startup.  Since you know "This code will validate before sending the mail", is the question about the code not running before sending the mail.

Comment: [Application_Startup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)

Comment: when i save the code and then try to send the mail without any subject or attachment. It works.

If i close the outlook application and then compose the mail and send an email without any subject line or attachment. This code doesn't work. 
That's the challenge. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Update Macro Security settings in the Trust Center.

Some links:

[Enable or disable macros in Office documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12?CorrelationId=3c5ce9df-59f4-49eb-a8a9-5aecb0e17f6f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Outlook 2013 & 2010: Enable or Disable Macros](http://www.technipages.com/outlook-enable-or-disable-macros)